# Super user binary source for Debian distro

Tags: debian, root, su, binary-files, source-code

I'm trying to craft a new root handle in a Debian distro and need to know where the source code for the su binary is located in order to move forward. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41640493/find-su-binary-source ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get any sources with two commands :

```
$ dpkg -S /bin/su
util-linux: /bin/su
$ apt source util-linux
```

The first commands indicates which package su belongs to, the second get the sources and extract its tar file. (I have know a `util-linux-2.33.1` directory).

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed to know.